# How to load URLS from before firebase before using them to fetch data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to load some URLs from a firebase database and fetch data from the urls but i get an error saying "Undefined is not a function" when i use this code:

```
listenForItems(itemsRef) {
    itemsRef.on('value', (snap) => {
      var items = [];
      snap.forEach((child) => {
        items.push({
          url: child.val().url,
          name: child.val().name,
          image: child.val().image,
          _key: child.key
        });
      });
      this.setState({ urls: items });
    }).then(() => {
      this.fetchData();
    });
  }
```

And when i remove the ".Then" it works but the fetched data keeps duplicating:

```
listenForItems(itemsRef) {
    itemsRef.on('value', (snap) => {
      var items = [];
      snap.forEach((child) => {
        items.push({
          url: child.val().url,
          name: child.val().name,
          image: child.val().image,
          _key: child.key
        });
      });
      this.setState({ urls: items });
      this.fetchData();
    })
  }
```

Comment: what if you add the fetch after setState finishes?

`this.setState({ urls: items }, this.fetchData);`

and dont add the then, also when do you call listenForItems?

Comment: `"Undefined is not a function"` surely there's some sort of indication as to which line in your code is responsible for this message - does `itemsRef.on` even return a promise? doesn't seem like the sort of function that would do so